# How to get details like duration, type, etc from uploaded videos and store them in fields?

Tags: media, files

I'm building a site that will handle a lot of media files, both image and video. Currently, I have video and image content types setup along with the ability to bulk-upload them.

I'm wondering if there is a way to scrape details from an uploaded video—such as duration, type, etc and store these in fields. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably we are talking mp4/webm video here? Start with checking out [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net). Then it is pretty simple to do:

```
$id3 = new getID3;
$file = $id3->analyze($filename);
```

Must always have "new getID3".

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me how I'd use this to pull info from a video on upload to populate some fields in a content item?

Comment: Depending on the type of video you want to import. For example with YouTube you can use [Feeds: YouTube Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_youtube). The simplest option is probably to write a custom module to populate the fields on node_form_submit().